# Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line (WMIC) support for different windows version

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am developing a few scripts depending upon Windows Management Instrumentation Command-line (WMIC). What is worrying me is support of WMIC for different versions of Windows.

I have found a few pages here and there. For example,

http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html points "WMIC is available on Vista/Windows 7, Windows XP Professional, but not Windows XP Home". But these links are quite old.

I have already checked WMIC in Windows 7. How to find what are the platforms WMIC support.

Can I assume in the following windows platforms, WMIC is available:

- Windows XP
- Windows 7 (32bit and 64bit version)
- Windows 2007 (32bit and 64bit version)
- Windows 2012 (32bit and 64bit version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WMIC is supported in every SKU of Windows after Windows XP, so, yes, you can assume it will be there.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394531(v=vs.85).aspx, which states the minimum version of the supported OSes as XP and Server 2003.

Answer (score 0):

You must aware for some changes about WMIC within XP to 7 even higher.
For example, Volume switch there is in Win7 but not WinXP.
I suggest to use and test with minimum state that is WinXP.